# how to handle the event when markers load into memory 

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps

i have many makers (maybe 500) to insert to maps, so i want to Optimization them

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'visible_changed', function() {
                alert('ww')
            });
```

this code  can't alert 'ww', when i zoom in the map(so some marker will not be seen)

why can't trigger  the 'visible_changed' event when zoomin

and  how to handle the event when the marker is loaded into memory,

and  how to handle the event when the marker is inserted into map,

thanks

Comment: What event? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Please post a link to your code, an excerpt of code like this isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to display this many markers you should be using marker clusterer or marker manager - they will do all the hard work for you - all you need to do is pass an array of marker objects to them. More info here http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries and a demo here

- Marker Manager
  http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/examples.html
- Marker Clusterer -
  http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html